# Monitor displays "no signal detected" message

Tags: display, graphics-card, signal

I recently bought a new monitor but when I connect it to my PC I only get a "no signal detected" message. The monitor works fine when I connect it to my laptop, and my PC also works otherwise. I tried 2 different cables (both of which are working since they were tested on other machines). I made sure each time the monitor was searching for the right input (HDMI, D-SUB). My graphic drivers are up to date. The monitor is from LG and the PC has a GeForce GTX 970 JetStream graphic card. I tried searching for similar problems (obviously) but it seems for other people it was usually a hardware or driver issue, which seems not to be the case. Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Is it possible that the PC is trying to display a resolution on the monitor that is not supported by the monitor?

Comment: Have you verified that the PC is putting out a video signal on the port(s) you're trying to use (does the old monitor still work if you reconnect it)?

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes the old monitor works fine still.

Comment: @Justin I'm not sure, how could i check for that (I have windows 8 if that's relevant)?

Comment: @Stacker Under Control Panel > Appearence and Personalization > Display, ensure that the second display is available and then set it for a low resolution to see if anything displays. Then step up the resolution until you reach the desired resolution that is available on the display.

Comment: @Justin The second display is not available, neither in the control panel nor NVIDIA control panel. The PC just doesnt seem to detect that monitor.

Comment: From what you describe, each piece of the puzzle is verified to work by itself, they just don't work together.  What was the resolution of the old monitor and what is the native resolution of the new one?  What are the models of the old and new displays?

Comment: @fixer1234 Yes that is pretty much it. The old monitor is 1366 x 768 and the new one is 1920 x 1080. I'm not sure what you mean by model of display, could you elaborate?

Comment: Manufacturer and model number.  You seem to have some odd compatibility problem.  It would really be helpful to have equipment like an inline tester to see what's going on with each conductor when the monitor is connected, or a signal splitter so you could connect another monitor simultaneously to the same port.